# 2x2 Grid equal height despite box content amount

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to create a 2x2 grid where the height of the four individual boxes (red, blue, green, yellow) are all equal despite how much content they contain.

```css
#rowTwo {
  background-color: pink;
  min-height: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  align-items: center;
}

#grid2x2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 80%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
  margin: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id={styles.rowTwo}>
  <Heading title="My Title"/>
  <div id={styles.grid2x2}>
    <div id={styles.boxOne} className={styles.box}>
        <DescriptionBoxItemWithHeading item={this.state.sectionTwoItems[0]}/>
    </div>
    <div id={styles.boxTwo} className={styles.box}>
        <DescriptionBoxItemWithHeading item={this.state.sectionTwoItems[1]}/>
    </div>
    <div id={styles.boxThree} className={styles.box}>
        <DescriptionBoxItemWithHeading item={this.state.sectionTwoItems[2]}/>
    </div>
    <div id={styles.boxFour} className={styles.box}>
        <DescriptionBoxItemWithHeading item={this.state.sectionTwoItems[3]}/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue I face is that a box expands to the height of the largest content in a row.

Here is an image outlining my problem:

[image]

Would anyone know how I could achieve this?

Comment: Please provide final generated HTML without any dynamic templating code...

Comment: This is not possible with flexbox. It can only equalise dimensions in one direction. You can have equal heights (in rows) or widths (in columns) but you can't have both at the same time. You need JS.

Comment: overflow-y: auto?

Comment: @Paulie_D How could I use JS to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS by using padding-top to add the height and then absolute positioning to draw your content on top of this padding.

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpwooz

```
#grid2x2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: orange;
}

.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
    margin: 5px;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
    padding-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is you can't change this height dynamically based on the content height. You can either set it to a fixed size or set it to a percentage and have it change size based on it's parents width. I think you'll need to use javascript if you want the height to change based on the largest content element.